# Keep getting C++ compile error for unknown reason

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have have just started using c++ and am trying to run a hello world program which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

but it keeps giving me errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::failed() const in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::failed() const in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in Hello-6e1fe4.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in Hello-6e1fe4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, could it be a compiler issue? I used both gcc and clang and they both gave the same result.

Comment: How do you call the compiler? (Command line?) Btw. the C++ compiler of gcc is called g++ (the one of clang is clang++). If you use gcc or clang instead it might be that the default config. for C++ is not available i.e. the compilers don't use the resp. C++ standard library by default.

Comment: Thanks, I was using `gcc Hello.cpp` and `clang Hello.cpp`. Seems to work now

Comment: [Comparison of gcc vs. g++ and clang vs. clang++ online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6a69980efe314ff)